# Distribution where mean and mean of reciprocal are both 1

Tags: distributions, mean, random-variable, expected-value

Is there a non-trivial distribution for a positive r.v. $X$ such that $\mathbb{E}(X) = \mathbb{E}\left(\frac{1}{X}\right) = 1$? If possible, I'd like the distribution to support (have positive probability for) the range (0, $\infty$).

If I could ask a follow-up, is there a family of distributions such that taking the reciprocal keeps you in that family?

Comment: Re follow-up: Taking the reciprocal of an F distribution gives you another F distribution with numerator and denominator degrees of freedom switched. // So some tables of F distributions are made only for upper tail probabilities.// Consider this example from R: Suppose you want `qf(.025, 10, 3)` which is 0.2072272; you can get it as `1/qf(.975, 3, 10)`, which is 0.2072272. (But of course printed tables have fewer decimal places of accuracy.)

Comment: Since the function $x \mapsto 1/x$ is convex on $(0,\,\infty)$ Jensen's inequality tells that $1 / \mathbb{E}[X] \leq \mathbb{E}[1/X]$. The function not being affine the inequality can be an equality only when $X$ is a constant almost surely.